# Add request and response detail from REST Assured test to Surefire report

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, rest-assured

[Rest Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) allows to write tests of REST endpoints. One of the useful features it has is the ability to [log the request and response in case of a failed test](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#logging) so you can check what was sent to the REST service.

### Request example

An example of a failing test which logs both the request and the response

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class TestRestAssured {
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();
  }

  @Test
  public void exampleFailingTest() {
    String json = "{\n" +
        "  \"title\": \"foo\",\n" +
        "  \"body\": \"bar\",\n" +
        "  \"userId\": 1\n" +
        "}";
    given()
        .contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        .body(json)
        .post("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then()
        .body("userId", equalTo(2));
  }
}
```

This test fails because the returned `userId` is 1. This is what's printed on the console when executing the test.

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Body:
{
    "title": "foo",
    "body": "bar",
    "userId": 1
}

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 65
Etag: W/"41-+JqcAMRWkzuXd+uFDZdzIA"
Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 08:18:59 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

{
    "title": "foo",
    "body": "bar",
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 101
}

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path userId doesn't match.
Expected: <2>
  Actual: 1


    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    [rest of the stacktrace]
```

### The problem

It is a great feature as it allows to report more contextful bug reports. Under the hood it uses a [`LogConfig`](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.0/io/restassured/config/LogConfig.html) which you can configure to write to any `PrintStream` defaulting to `System.out`.

The [Maven Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) reports errors on two files (text and XML). But on these files it **only includes the content from the exception thrown by the test method**. So the detail from the report looks like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path userId doesn't match.
Expected: <2>
  Actual: 1


    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    [rest of the stacktrace]
```

Which is nice but could be nicer.

### The question

Should be pretty obvious by now.

**How can I include the request and response detail from REST Assured on the Surefire report?**

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here: [Set restAssured to log all requests and responses globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259851/set-restassured-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-globally)

I start by importing log filters, like this

```
import io.restassured.filter.log.*;
```

Then I add the filters to the given() chain, like this

```
RequestSpecification myRequest = RestAssured.given()
                                            .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                                            .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter());
```

I could then see the raw request and response in my test output directly.