# Set restAssured to log all requests and responses globally

Tags: java, rest, logging, rest-assured

I want to enable logging for all `RestAssured` responses and requests by default.

Here's what I do:

```
RestAssured.requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder().
        setBaseUri("api").
        setContentType(ContentType.JSON).
        build().
        log().all();
RestAssured.responseSpecification = new ResponseSpecBuilder().
        build().
        log().all();
```

`requestSpecification` works alright, but with `responseSpecification` I get:

> Cannot configure logging since request specification is not defined.
> You may be misusing the API.

I really don't want to use `log().all()` after each then.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add logging filters to RestAssured defaults, see [filters](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#filters) and [defaults](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#default-values).

> To create a filter you need to implement the io.restassured.filter.Filter interface. To use a filter you can do:
>   given().filter(new MyFilter()). ..
>
> There are a couple of filters provided by REST Assured that are ready to use:
>    1. io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter: A filter that'll print the request specification details.
>    2. io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter: A filter that'll print the response details if the response matches a given status code.
>    3. io.restassured.filter.log.ErrorLoggingFilter: A filter that'll print the response body if an error occurred (status code is between 400 and 500)

Any filter could be added to request, spec or global defaults:

> RestAssured.filters(..); // List of default filters

Comment: Thanks, I just added ResponseLoggingFilter to requestSpecification. ```addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())```

Answer (score 35):

Put this line of code on your `@BeforeClass` method and every given call will create a log just like using log.all() after every given:

```
RestAssured.filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter());
```

Rest-Assured project:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/rest-assured/src/main/java/io/restassured/filter/log/RequestLoggingFilter.java

Answer (score 32):

I think you need to see the logs then test fails, in this case just use this configuration from rest assured:

`RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();`

Comment: In what context? I tried putting that line in `@BeforeClass` but got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/groovy/io/StringBuilderWriter`

Comment: For `JUnit Jupyter` I added it on `@BeforeEach`

Answer (score 1):

You can define filters at the class level

```
public ClassName() {
    filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter(), new ErrorLoggingFilter());
}
```